# How to remove Unwanted Objects from Photo in Android

Tags: android, photo

I am new in Android developing i want to build a photography app in which i want to remove an unwanted object or some part of image from Image .Is it possible if yes than how to implement it.Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please do some research and try to ask about a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a yes or no question because it really depends on what you are trying to remove from the picture and what is going to be instead of that object in the picture

If it's just a few pixels you should be able to replace this pixels with the average of the pixels around the object but I get the feeling that this is not what you want.

You don't know what data is "under" the object therefore you can't cut out a part of a picture without either leaving a hole in the picture or making a smaller image that not include the object(assuming the object is in the edge on the picture and align perfectly with the width or height of the image)